# Не могу сделать форму для поиска в django3

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, поиск

вот мой views

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import *
from django.views.generic import ListView


# simplePost

# Create your views here.
def index(req):
  posts = simplePost.objects.all()
  data = {
      "posts": posts
  }
  return render(req, 'main/index.html', data)


class search(ListView):
  def get_queryset(self):
      return simplePost.objects.filter(title=self.request.GET.get('q'))

  def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
      context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
      context["q"] = self.request.GET.get('q')

      return context
```

Вот `simplePost_list.html` (результаты поиска должны быть здесь)

```html
{% extends '../base/base.html' %}
{% block title %}
Результат Поиска
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
     <div class="content">
     {% for i in context %}
         <div class="post important_{{ i.important }}">
             <h3 class="title">{{ i.title }}</h3>
             <p class="text">{{ i.text }}</p>
             <b class="date">{{ i.date }}</b>
         </div>
     {% endfor %}
     </div>
{% endblock %}
```

сама форма

```html
<form action="{% url 'search' %}" method="get" class="search-form" required="">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="search" name="q" class="search" placeholder="Поиск записей 
  в блоге">
</form></li>
```

Простите что криво)

при поиске названия модели simplePost
строка поиска работает правильно но ничего не выводиться,
подскажите. вдруг зря паникую)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Очень странная фраза *поиска работает правильно но ничего не выводиться*

На самом деле скорее всего у вас поиск и работает правильно. Но вы ошиблись с выводом результата поиска в шаблон.
Вместо `{% for i in context %}` надо писать `{%for i in object_list%}`
Но конечно лучше будет в класс поиска (во `views`) добавить что-то вроде

```
context_object_name="result_serch"
```

и тогда в шаблоне

```
{%for i in result_serch%}
```

**P.S.** [подробнее о `context_object_name` в документации](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#making-friendly-template-contexts)

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!